# Prove that $|x| = \max_{f \in E^\star \setminus \{0\}} \frac{\langle f, x \rangle}{\|f\|}$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

I'm trying to prove below duality result. Could you have a check on my proof?

> Let $(E, |\cdot |)$ be a normed linear space and $(E^\star, \| \cdot \|)$ its continuous dual. As usual, $$\|f\| := \sup_{x \in E \setminus \{0\}} \frac{\langle f, x \rangle}{|x|}, \quad \forall f\in E^\star.$$ Then $$|x| = \max_{f \in E^\star \setminus \{0\}} \frac{\langle f, x \rangle}{\|f\|}, \quad \forall x\in E.$$

**My attempt:** Fix $x\in E$. The claim clearly holds for $x=0$. Let's assume that $x \neq 0$. It follows from the definition of $\| \cdot \|$ that $$\|f\| \ge \frac{\langle f, x \rangle}{|x|}, \quad \forall f \in E^\star.$$

This in turn implies $$|x| \ge \frac{\langle f, x \rangle}{\|f\|}, \quad \forall f \in E^\star \setminus \{0\}.$$

Then $$|x| \ge \sup_{f \in E^\star \setminus \{0\}} \frac{\langle f, x \rangle}{\|f\|}.$$

Let $G := \mathbb Rx$. Then $G$ is a linear subspace of $E$. Consider $g: G \to \mathbb R, tx \mapsto t|x|^2$. Then $g \in G^\star$ and $\|g\| = |x|$. By Hahn-Banach theorem, $g$ admits a linear continuous extension $\tilde g \in E^\star$ such that $\|\tilde g\| = \|g\|$. Then $$\sup_{f \in E^\star \setminus \{0\}} \frac{\langle f, x \rangle}{\|f\|} \ge \frac{\langle \tilde g, x \rangle}{\|\tilde g\|} = \frac{|x|^2}{|x|} = |x|.$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: One should, however, note that the result fails in $E = \{0\}$ (or, at least, depends on the definition of $\max$ over an empty set).